# Google Data Studio Sum with Conditions

Tags: google-analytics, business-intelligence, looker-studio

I have one metric and one dimension
I need to create a calculated field like SQL Query:

```
sum(new_users) where event_action= "manual_widget_click" / Total_new_Users
```

I can not understand the logic of formulas in Data Studio.
Not here standard functions like 'sumif' or 'where'....
only 'Case When'. But I can not put together a formula...

[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample report (w/o any real data) with editing permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by breaking down the formula into 2 Calculated Fields.

First :

```
CASE
  WHEN event_action= "manual_widget_click" THEN new_users
  ELSE 0
END
```

Then :

```
SUM(event_action= "manual_widget_click" THEN new_users) / Total_new_Users
```